# How to get return values from pure C function to swift?

Tags: ios, c, function, swift

I have a doubt, how to get the returned value from pure `c` function to swift.

Here my code:

In  `ViewController.swift` // swift file

```
var name = getPersonName()
```

In `personList.h` // C header file

```
char getPersonName();
```

In `personList.c`// pure C file

```
#include personList.h

char getPersonName() {
    char* name = "Hello, Swift";
    return name;
}
```

Here already i linked personList.h file through bridge using `MyProjectName-Bridging-Header.h`.

Thanks

Comment: In any case,  the return type of the function does not match the type of the returned value. So your function is wrong, and also the syntax for `#include` directive is not like yours.

Comment: did you mean `char *getPersonName()`?

Comment: getPersonName() is a function, i am returning some vale from c code how can i get it in swift?

Comment: I would surmise valid C code would be the first requirement.

Comment: @Ravi, ok, `char* getPersonName()`, better now? :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I tried like that also its returning integer not string.  i am getting error like this 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> not convertible '

Comment: @Ravi: If you want the function to return an integer then you should declare it as `int someFunction()`. Then you will have no problem at all to assign the value to a Swift variable. – Currently your code is confusing because you have declared it to return `char`, but actually it returns a `char *`.

Comment: @MartinR : I need string not integer, what i am saying is even if i gave return type as char i am not getting string, i am getting int but i need string value, how can i get string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the C function to return a string then the return type should be
`char *` or better `const char *`:

```
// personList.h:
const char *getPersonName(void);

// personList.c:
const char *getPersonName(void)
{
    char *name = "Hello, Swift";
    return name;
}
```

This is imported to Swift as

```
func getPersonName() -> UnsafePointer<Int8>
```

and you can create a Swift string from the returned pointer with

```
let name = String.fromCString(getPersonName())!
println(name) // Output: Hello, Swift

// Swift 3:
let name = String(cString: getPersonName())
print(name) // Output: Hello, Swift
```

"Hooray," you'll say, "that's what I need." – **But wait!!**
This works only because `"Hello, Swift"` in the C function is a *string literal*. Normally you cannot return a pointer to a local variable from
a function, because the memory that the pointer points to may not be
valid after return from the function. If the pointer does not point
to static memory then you have to *duplicate* it. Example:

```
const char *getPersonName(void)
{
    char name[200];
    snprintf(name, sizeof name, "%s %s", "Hello", "Swift!");
    return strdup(name);
}
```

but now the caller has to *deallocate* the memory eventually:

```
let cstr = getPersonName()
let name = String.fromCString(cstr)!
free(UnsafeMutablePointer(cstr))

println(name)
```

Alternatively, you can change the C function so that the caller
passes the memory instead:

```
void getPersonName(char *name, size_t nameSize)
{
    snprintf(name, nameSize, "%s %s", "Hello", "Swift!");
}
```

which would be used from Swift as

```
var nameBuf = [Int8](count: 200, repeatedValue: 0) // Buffer for C string
getPersonName(&nameBuf, UInt(nameBuf.count))
let name = String.fromCString(nameBuf)!
println(name)

// Swift 3:
var nameBuf = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: 200) // Buffer for C string
getPersonName(&nameBuf, nameBuf.count)
let name = String(cString: nameBuf)
print(name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i need some more help on this concept.
I have In C : struct record { 
char* name;
wchar_t *serialNumber;
}
 and   
struct record  getRecord() {
  // Setting some values to name and serial number
return record;
 } .

In Swift
var details = getRecord();

Now how can i get name and serialNumber?