# Swift - C++ string via C API

Tags: c++, swift

I have Swift with bridge to C API

I wan to do something like this:

```
const char * CApiFunc(){
    std::string str = "some_str";

    return str.c_str()
}
```

but it will lead to problem, since `str` is removed from stack and returned address is incorrect. Is there any other way than to copy `std::string` to newly allocated array and return pointer to this array, like this:

```
const char * CApiFunc2(){
    std::string str = "some_str";
    char * tmp = new char[str.length() + 1];
    memcpy(tmp, str.c_str(), str.length());
    tmp[str.length()] = 0;
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really seem to have anything at all to do with Swift or C.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I thought if there is a way like eg. pass Swift String as a parametr to the function and fill it on C or C++ side. In this way, it is a Swift based question

Comment: A possible alternative would be to pass an array as storage to the C function, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090910/how-to-get-return-values-from-pure-c-function-to-swift.

Comment: The best wrapper approach I have seen so far was proposed by [Miles Budnek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151599/miles-budnek): [*convert an std::string to a Swift String*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49806613/192373).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't another way.

A `std::string`, by design, owns its buffer. If you don't want the data to die when the string does, you'll have to copy it into a new buffer.

In this contrived example there's really no need for the `std::string` in the first place, but I'm sure you know that and have a more solid use case.