# convert an std::string to a Swift String

Tags: c++, swift, static-libraries, bridge

**Short version:**

how can I convert an `std::string` (object returned by a .cpp function called from a .Swift file using bridging) to a Swift `String`?

**Long version:**

I have a library written in C++ and I have to call some code using Swift. I created a bridge, adding two files in my Xcode projects:

a bridging header, which allows Swift to call C functions (afaik Swift can't call C++ functions directly, so it needs to pass through C functions)

```
//file bridgingHeader.h
const char * getLastOpenedFile();
```

and a .cpp files which can call (of course) C++ functions inside and can define C functions with extern "C"

```
//file wrapper.cpp    
#include <string>
#include "my_library.hpp"

extern "C" const char * getStringFromLibrary()
{
    const char * s = get_string_from_library().c_str();
    return s;
}
```

I can access the return value from a .swift file using

```
let myString = String(cString: getStringFromLibrary())
Swift.print(myString)
```

Placing a breakpoint to check the value of `s` inside the function `getStringFromLibrary()` I can see the content of the string, so the function from the library is correctly called.

Anyway the .swift file prints some strange symbols and not the original string.
Changing `getStringFromLibrary()` to be the following

```
extern "C" const char * getStringFromLibrary()
{        
    return get_string_from_library().c_str();
}
```

I have as a consequence that the .swift code prints a prefix of the real string. This makes me think of a problem of memory: probably when `getStringFromLibrary()` exits, the `std::string` object returned by `get_string_from_library()` is destroyed, and so the memory pointed by the pointer returned with `.c_str()` is not reliable anymore, reason why I get wrong outputs from `Swift.print()`.

What is the correct way to access an `std::string` from a .swift file and then release its memory?

Comment: Your `getStringFromLibrary` will be hanging onto a dangling pointer since `s` refers to a `const char*` that was allocated, and destroyed by, the `get_string_from_library` function. I am not familiar with swift, but you'll essentially have to heap allocate that `const char*` and give ownership to the caller.

Comment: maybe a solutions is to call malloc inside getStringFromLibrary() for allocating memory for a `char *` variable, copying the content of the variable to a Swift string and then calling `free()` explicitly

Comment: @Nisba Yes, that is the usual way to it.  You may consider adding a `freeStringFromLibrary` function instead of calling `free` directly from Swift so that the underlying method of memory allocation is hidden. 
 That would let you use `new[]` or `malloc` internally.

Answer (score 5):

You can write an Objective-C++ wrapper to work with C++ codes.

bridging header:

```
#include "Wrapper.hpp"
```

Wrapper.hpp:

```
#ifndef Wrapper_hpp
#define Wrapper_hpp

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif
    NSString * _Nonnull getStringFromLibrary();
#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif

#endif /* Wrapper_hpp */
```

Wrapper.mm:

```
#include "Wrapper.hpp"

#include <string>
#include "my_library.hpp"

NSString * _Nonnull getStringFromLibrary() {
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:get_string_from_library().c_str()];
}
```

Swift code:

```
print(getStringFromLibrary())
```

`[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]` copies the contents of the buffer into some internal storage and ARC manages freeing it. You have no need to define `free_something()`.

Answer (score 4):

The `std::string` object owns the buffer to which a pointer is returned via `c_str`.  That means that `getStringFromLibrary` returns a pointer to nothing.

There are several ways you could avoid that:

1) Copy the contents of the buffer somewhere long-lived, and return a pointer to that.  This usually means allocating some memory via `new[]` or `malloc`:

```
extern "C"
{

const char* getStringFromLibrary()
{
    std::string str = get_string_from_library();
    char* s = new char[str.size() + 1]{};
    std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), s);
    return s;
}

void freeStringFromLibrary(char* s)
{
    delete[] s;
}

}
```

This method is simple, but it does incur the cost of an extra copy.  That may or may not be relevant depending on how big `str` is and how often `getStringFromLibrary` is called.  It also requires the user to deal with resource management, so it's not particularly exception-safe.

2) Return a opaque "handle" to a `std::string` object and let swift access its underlying buffer and free it by different functions:

```
extern "C"
{

void* getStringFromLibrary()
{
    std::string* s = new std::string(get_string_from_library());
    return s;
}

const char* libraryGetCString(void* s)
{
    return static_cast<std::string*>(s)->c_str();
}

void freeStringFromLibrary(void* s)
{
    delete static_cast<std::string*>(s);
}

}
```

Now in swift you can do something like this:

```
let handle: UnsafeMutablePointer<COpaquePointer> = getStringFromLibrary()
let myString = String(cString: libraryGetCString(handle))
freeStringFromLibrary(handle)
```

This approach eliminates the extra copy, but it's still not exception-safe since the caller has to deal with resource management.

There's likely a way to mix Objective-C++ into the solution to avoid the issue with resource management, but sadly I'm not familiar enough with Swift or Objective-C++ to tell you what that solution looks like.

Comment: isn't the extra copy just hidden in `std::string* s = new std::string(get_string_from_library());`?

Comment: No, the string returned by `get_string_from_library` will be moved into the new `string` object.  This only requires a pointer copy instead of copying the whole string.

Comment: going for style points with the first approach: use `strdup()` and `free()` instead of `new`/`copy`/`delete[]`.

Answer (score 2):

I define a function (it could be a static `String` extension, if you prefer):

```
func getStringAndFree(_ cString: UnsafePointer<Int8>) -> String {
    let res = String(cString: cString)
    cString.deallocate()
    return res
}
```

and in C++,

```
extern "C" char *getStringFromLibrary()
{
    return strdup(get_string_from_library().c_str());
}
```

Now in Swift, I can simply use this in a fire-and-forget way:

```
print("String from C++ is: " + getStringAndFree(getStringFromLibrary()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved, I post the solution I ended up with.

In the future I will probably write a class which will allow me to manage the delete operation in an automatic an safer way. I will update the answer.

bridging header:

```
//file bridgingHeader.h
char * getStringFromLibrary();
void freeString(char * string);
```

wrapper:

```
char * std_string_to_c_string(std::string s0) {
    size_t length = s0.length() + 1;
    char * s1 = new char [length];
    std::strcpy(s1, s0.c_str());
    return s1;
}

extern "C" void freeString(char * string) {    
    delete [] string;
}

extern "C" char * getStringFromLibrary()
{
    return std_string_to_c_string(get_string_from_library().c_str());
}
```

Swift code:

```
let c_string: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>! = getStringFromLibrary()
let myString = String(cString: c_string)
freeString(c_string)

Swift.print(myString)
```